# AnyLogic location of population

Tags: process, anylogic, population

I created a function to move agents from my population (database) into a process.

Somehow it throws an Error

```
Exception during discrete event execution:
root.<population>[0]:
This agent isn't located in any space
```

The goal of my model is that transporters arrive at certain arrival times (the same date as in the model) from a dataset in my factory:

[image]

[image]

My steps until now:

1. Create a population with agents of the type of my agents and fill them with the values of my data
2. create an event which checks every minute for all objects of my population if their arrival time equals the models time
3. Write a function that enters them into my process and on the road to come to my factory

Therefor every transporter exists already before being entered into my process so that the event can check the condition.

My problem:
When the condition is true and the object should enter my process an error occurs:

```
Exception during discrete event execution:
    root.<population>[0]:
    This agent isn't located in any space
```

I don't understand why they dont have their initial space already.
I tried to set the space on the enter block with `agent.setSpace(getSpace())`but nothing changed. My population is also in the main method
[image]
Properties of pop:
[image]

[image]

properties agent:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Agents are not data. They need a space. By default, it is the space of the ebmedding agent of their population (typically `Main` if the population is on `Main`).

If your `Enter` block is not in the same agent as the population was beforehand, you need to call `agent.setSpace(getSpace())` in the "on enter" code box of the "Enter" block.

This should assign the agents to use the new space of the embedding agent

Comment: When I give the objects a rectangle as home, it sometimes throws this error //

root.mplkws[-1]:
This agent is already defined as agent living in space 'Discrete 2D' and can't have behaviour for space 'Continuous'//

and otherwise the original error

Comment: You will have to provide more details. Many of the things you write don't actually make sense, tbh ("population to store an individual dataset", " population to store an individual dataset", ...) so maybe some screenshots and more info can clarify the problem.

Comment: The question was edited and my problem clarified. I hope, that it makes more sense now.

Comment: Did you create the agents using the add_MyPopulation(...) method?

Comment: No, I used the Agent block and chose 'population' and 'Use database table' . I did not use any functions for the creation. I also have never created and used a population before so maybe there is a mistake

Comment: Pls show the properties of the population

Comment: Looks fine. Try recreating the problem from scratch. Isolate it to what is causing the error. Maybe it's using the dbase, so exclude that. Maybe it is the event, so do it in a different way. Only create one agent. Play Sherlock Holmes to find the root cause